# How to open multiple files from the quick open menu in Visual Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'd like to know if it is possible to open multiple files from the quick open menu in Visual Code (opened with `cmd + p` shortcut by default).

It would be helpful to be able to select the N first files in the results to open them at once. For instance, I could type "test_device*.js", and could open the 3 first files which are "test_device_usecase_1.js", "test_device_usecase_2.js" & "test_device_usecase_3.js", instead of having to perform more searches to open the remaining 2 files.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use arrow right <kbd>→</kbd> to open selected file without closing quick open.

Comment: Dear lord, I owe you my life.

Comment: that's incredible trick, works like a charm